# Fixing a corrupted geometry column with Python GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I had a shapefile which I converted to a geodataframe, and created a geometry column. I did some manipulation with it in pandas. I am now trying to convert it back into a geodataframe and eventually a shapefile but cannot make it work. I have tried the usual methods:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.read_csv('DirectMail.csv')
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='GEOMETRY__C')
```

and get the following error. This is the first row in the dataframe by the way:

`TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: MULTIPOLYGON (((1241887.500623662 949342.9993114918, 1241827.375743911...`

After looking at other Stack Overflow threads I tried this way using shapely wkt

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt

df = pd.read_csv('DirectMail.csv')
df['GEOMETRY__C'] = df['GEOMETRY__C'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

and I get this error:

`WKTReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.`

If I check to see if the geometries in the 'GEOMETRY__C' column are valid like this...

```
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely as sh

gdf = gpd.read_file("DirectMail.csv")

gdf['validation'] = gdf['GEOMETRY__C']
```

I have the following result:

```
0   False
1   False
2   False
```

and so on...

This makes me wonder, is the 'GEOMETRY__C' column in the wrong data type?  I checked the data type of this column and it is pandas `dtype('O')`

Does anyone have other suggestions what I can do?  Do I need to changes the datatype of the geometry column?

Comment: Check if it is valid or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833344/fix-invalid-polygon-in-shapely